# Problema con el Triángulo de Pascal en C

Tags: c

Estoy intentando calcular el Triángulo de Pascal y consigo hacer la primera columna y la diagonal, pero el resto se me está atragantando un poco. En la salida, parece que en vez de dar los valores de la tabla, indica la dirección en memoria.

¿Alguien podría orientarme un poco?

Muchas Gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int tabla[16][16];
    int fila = 0, col = 0;
    int numero;

    printf("Escribe el número de filas de la tabla: ");
    scanf("%d", &numero);

    /* Cada fila se calcula a partir de la anterior, hay que inicializarla  */
    /* para poder realizar el cáculo de las ciguientes.                     */
    tabla[0][0] = 1;
    printf("%-5d\n", tabla[0][0]);

    /* El bucle de cálculo y visualización empieza en la fila 1.            */
    for(fila = 1; fila < numero; fila++)
    {
        /* Cada columna de una fila se calcula a partir de dos valores de la    */
        /* fila anterior. Este cálculo no es posible para la columna 0 y para   */
        /* la columna diagonal, que deben contener 1.                           */
        
        /* Columna 0 */
        tabla[fila][0] = 1;
        printf("%-5d", tabla[fila][0]);

        /* Bucle sobre las columna de la 1 a la diagonal (no incluida). */
        for(col = 1; col < fila; col++);
        {
            tabla[fila][col] = tabla[fila - 1][col] + tabla[fila - 1][col - 1];
            printf("%-5d", tabla[fila][col]);
        }

        /* Diagonal */
        /* Mismo valor para la fila y la columna, forman la diagonal. */
        tabla[fila][fila] = 1;
        printf("%-5d\n", tabla[fila][fila]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hecho. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(col = 1; col < fila; col++);
```

Fíjate en ese punto y coma del final del for. Eso  hace que el for **no ejecute nada**.

Elimina ese punto y coma y empezarás a ver algo que parece un triángulo

Comment: ¡Alaaaa! ¡que desastre! Perdona por hacerte perder el tiempo, me fijaré mucho más a la próxima. Muchas gracias.